# quorum-maker-no web UI is exposing on any host ports after creating nodes

Tags: quorum

Im trying to deploy contract using quorum-maker, I've followed every step as mentioned in wiki, but still not able to connect web UI and have no idea where Web app is deployed(in wiki. http://10.50.0.2:22004).
BTW I'm trying on GCP instance and AWS instance also. here is my docker ps status.[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are running in your local machine , then try accessing the UI make on 0.0.0.0:22000 and replace 22000 with the port number for the node you want to see the UI maker .
In case you are running on any cloud services, try to check that 
1. IP is publically accessible.
2. Ports are open and listening.